# 'Duplicate' NGram values in topic list created using bertopic

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I've set the CountVectorizer to examine bi and trigrams (ngram_range=(1, 3)) . This seems very useful. However, I'm seeing "duplicate" terms e.g.:

[image: topics]

The terms "justice," "India," "gate," and "along" appear to overlap significantly. I'm utilising these vocabularies to choose documents for further processing, and it appears that we have one phrase "pushing out" other terms that could otherwise surface. In fact, I'm conducting a broad search across all of these terms to pick target documents for additional processing, so I'm not sure what I'm "missing" otherwise. Is this something I'm thinking about correctly? In this case, would it be a "good thing" if "india gate" and "justice khanna" were combined into a single term?

also how can I combine these into a single term in bertopic so that these overlaps don't occur

Answer (score 1):

In BERTopic, there is the `diversity` parameter that allows you to fine-tune the topic representations. The underlying algorithm for this is called [MaximalMarginalRelevance](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/algorithm/algorithm.html#6-optional-maximal-marginal-relevance). It is a value between 0 and 1 that indicates how diverse keywords in a single topic should be compared to one another. A value of 1 indicates high diversity and 0 indicates little diversity. It works as follows:

```py
from bertopic import BERTopic
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

# Get documents
docs = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all',  remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))['data']

# Train BERTopic and apply MMR
topic_model = BERTopic(diversity=0.4)
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)
```

Do note that in the upcoming version, the `diversity` parameter is removed and will be replaced as follows:

```py
from bertopic.representation import MaximalMarginalRelevance
from bertopic import BERTopic

# Create your representation model
representation_model = MaximalMarginalRelevance(diversity=0.3)

# Use the representation model in BERTopic on top of the default pipeline
topic_model = BERTopic(representation_model=representation_model)
```